# My Adobe Photoshop does not contain quick export as png option

Tags: adobe-photoshop, export

I have created a group in Adobe photoshop, and I want to export this group of layers as png.

But when I right click on the group folder from layer view, then there appears to be no option as export as png.

> So is there any alternative way of exporting layer group as png?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**If you are using an older version of PS (prior to CC2015), here's an easy workaround, wihtout the need to install external scripts:**

Do the following steps and save them as an [action](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/how-to/photoshop-record-action.html). Optionally bind it to an F-key for a faster  workflow:

1. Select the layers you want to export
2. Right-click and select *Duplicate layers...*
3. Under *Destination* set *New* as the *Document*
4. Click *OK*
5. Switch to the new document
6. In the menu, navigate to *Image* > *Trim*
7. Select *Transparent Pixels* and everything under *Trim away*
8. Click *OK*

-- end action recording here, name it 'Copy to new and trim' and assign an F-key (e.g. F2)

9. Navigate to *File* > *Save for Web* or use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> and save as a PNG.

---

Next time, all you have to do is:

1. Select the layers
2. Hit <kbd>F2</kbd>
3. Hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>

---

[image: steps to duplicate layers to a new document and trim empty space]

Answer (score 2):

The *Quick export as PNG* option was only added in Photoshop CC 2015.

If you are using an older version, here's a workaround:

Hide every *other* layer and group, then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> which opens the 'Save for Web' panel which allows you to save PNGs.

Comment: But this option doesn't allow me to select a group of layers and save it as png. It instead saves the whole psd to png.

Comment: You can manually select by hiding layers which should not be included. As for _why_ you don't see the 'Quick Export' option, i wouldn't know.

Comment: @Lucian I found an alternative hack. First I saved the whole psd as temporary png file. Then I cropped only the portion I need and then I resaved it. It works but its time consuming. It would be a lot better if my version contained `quick export as png option.`

Comment: @PranKumarSarkar, very long time ago I actually used to have an Action that duplicates the selected layers to a new document and trims the background to transparent. A simple two step action. Then all I had to do was save the document. Which even now is not the worst workflow depending on the type of exporting you do. Although nowadays in PS CC we just add the file format extension to the layer(s) and PS automatically exports them when the PSD doc is saved.

Comment: There used to be many scripts and extensions for PS prior to CC versions I had a hard time finding any of those extensions... but I found one for cs5 and cs 6 http://www.pngexpress.com/ ← see their user guide under support for install instructions.